# Routing rule to pass _any_ id value to controller

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I've got the following route

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name:="Gallery",
    url:="{controller}/{action}/{*id}",
    defaults:=New With {
        .controller = "Gallery",
        .action = "Index",
        .id = UrlParameter.Optional},
    constraints:=New With {.id = ".*"}
)
```

I'm attempting to match urls like the following:

- /Gallery/Thumb/SomeDirectory
- /Gallery/Thumb/SomeDirectory/
- /Gallery/Thumb/SomeDirectory/SomeImage.jpg

In each case, I'd expect the `Thumb` action of the `GalleryController` to be called with the appropriate path.

At present,

```
/Gallery/Thumb/SomeDirectory = 404.0 (Seems it doesn't match a route, passes straight through to IIS 404)
/Gallery/Thumb/SomeDirectory/ = Works
/Gallery/Thumb/SomeDirectory/SomeImage.jpg = 404.0 (Same as above)
/Gallery/Thumb/SomeDirectory/SomeImage = Works (routing works, although the path supplied in Id isn't a useful one)
```

What do I need to do with my route to pass *everything* after the action through in the id?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is maybe the Dot in your Id, you could UrlEncode it ?

Comment: You may well be right but a full stop isn't a reserved character requiring encoding (at least not in regard to urls) - http://stackoverflow.com/a/6191428/156755 - Using `%2E` doesn't resolve the problem either, in fact Chrome converts it back to a `.`